# Prove that a function is zero.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ such that

$$\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) x^n dx = 0$$

for all $n=0,1,2,\ldots$. So I want to show that $f=0$.

Then I was triying to prove that $\forall \epsilon>0 |f(x)|<\epsilon$ but the thing is that I can only ensure that
$$|\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) x^n dx |< \epsilon$$

so I don't get any relationship between $f$ and $\epsilon$ doing that, then I thought that the Weirstrass theorem could help here since we have polynomials, but I don't know how to apply it, I was wondering to show that 
$$\displaystyle \int_a^b f^2dx = 0$$

or some relation of that sort using Weierstrass, but I don't know how, and another thing that I had in mind is that Is it possible to give a non trivial example of a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x)dx = \int_0^1 f(x) x dx = \int_0^1 f(x)x^2dx = 0.?$$

Then, Can someone help me with my questions please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: A proof sketch can be found in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102388/proving-that-int-01-fxenx-rm-dx-0-for-all-n-in-mathbbn-0-impl/1102420#1102420).

Comment: And for the example?

Comment: The function $f(x) = x^3-\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{3 x}{5}-\frac{1}{20}$ has $\int_0^1 f = \int_0^1 x f = \int_0^1 x^2 f = 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition implies $\int f . P=0$ for every polynomial. Take a sequence $P_n$ of polynomials converging uniformly to $f$. Then,

$$\int f^2= \int f.f= \lim \int f.P_n=\lim 0=0.$$

For your second question... instead of giving an example, I will give a lot at once:

$$\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle:C([0,1], \mathbb{R}) \times C([0,1], \mathbb{R})  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$ f, g \mapsto \int fg $$

is an inner product. $C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ is obviously infinite dimensional. Take any function in $(x)^\perp \cap (x^2)^{\perp} $. (This justifies why Legendre Polynomials (as suggested by Sangchul) are a good idea to search for an explicit example.)

Comment: Thanks, and Can you give an example of a non trivial example of a zero integral ( as in my post)?

Comment: @user162343, Legendre polynomials would serve good examples to your question.

Comment: Which ones are those polynimials?

Comment: Do you mean this ones[SM][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials] (The ones deived from the Rodrigues formula) ?

Answer (score 1):

For nontrivial $f$ such that $\int_0^1 f(x) x^k\; dx = 0$ for $k = 0, 1, 2$, try e.g. $f$ of the form $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2  + a_3 x^3$.  In this $4$-dimensional pace, there should be a $1$-dimensional subspace satisfying your constraints.