# Show that $f=0$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

I found this problem while going through some old question papers of a test I'm preparing for:

> Let $f: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be a bounded measurable function such that $\int_0^1 f(t) e^{nt} dt = 0$ for every $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ Prove that $f(t)=0$ for almost every $t \in [0,1]$.

I've seen similar questions before where $e^{nt}$ was replaced by $t^n$ or $t^{2n}$. They could be solved by using the Stone-Weierstrass approximations of $\cos(2 \pi nt),\sin(2 \pi nt)$ and then looking at the Fourier series of $f$. Again, if we had $e^{int}$ then we could've used use Parseval's identity as $f \in L^2$.

But I've no idea how to continue with this particular problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Stone Weirestrass Theorem gives the answer since linear combinations of $e^{nt}$ form an algebre which separates points and contains constants.

Comment: You can try the change of variable $s=e^t$. That may help.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1102388/42969

Comment: @geetha290krm Sorry, I was totally missing your point...